When do raise_errors_for_deprecations! and raise_on_warning trigger?
Ruby: 3.4.0-preview1
rspec: 3.13.0
.rspec
--warning

spec_helper.rb
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../lib', __dir__)
require 'rspec/its'

RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!
   config.raise_on_warning = true
   config.warnings = true
   config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
     c.syntax = :expect
   end
end

test_spec.rb
require_relative './spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Test' do
  it "test" do
    expect(''.concat('test')).to eq('test')
  end
end

Output
Test

/home/user/git/test_project/spec/test_spec.rb:5: warning: literal string will be frozen in the future

 test

Finished in 0.00121 seconds (files took 0.10739 seconds to load)

1 example, 0 failures

Maybe I understood the configs raise_errors_for_deprecations! and raise_on_warning wrong, but shouldn't my test fail when a warning is thrown? What do I have to change to make the test fail?

I think raise_on_warning only applies to RSpec warnings. Confusing. It sets RSpec::Support.warning_notifier which is only used in the internal RSpec method RSpec::Support#warn_with. See this code search. You might want to raise an issue with rspec-core to ask them to clarify.

Turns out, that none of these config options are related to ruby warnings, they just consider warning/deprecations from rspec directly. Therefore the behaviour is expected.
See GitHub issue
